# How to modify a class instance attribute in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to learn C# by building a basic IOS map application.

I'm having trouble understanding how I should be modifying attributes in the `my_map` class instance. Should it be in a overridden `ViewController` constructor or is there a special method it should be in similar to `ReleaseDesignerOutlets()`?

```
    // actions declared in your storyboard file.
    // Manual changes to this file will not be maintained.
    //
    using Foundation;
    using System;
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
    using UIKit;

    namespace my_mapp_app
    {
        [Register ("ViewController")]
        partial class ViewController
        {
            [Outlet]
            [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
            MapKit.MKMapView my_map{ get; set; }

            # Problem code
            my_map.MapType = MapKit.MKMapType.Hybrid;
            my_map.ZoomEnabled = true;
            # End problem code 

            void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
            {

                if (my_map != null) {
                    my_map.Dispose ();
                    my_map = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off this example
https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/MapDemo/MapDemo/MapViewController.cs

I learned that you should change the attributes in the parent UIViewController method ViewDidLoad() so that it the attributes are changed after the view finishes loading.